# Empty while loop never exits in Processing

Tags: loops, while-loop, processing, webcam

I'm trying to catch two consecutive frames from a webcam, and I tried doing it the following way.

```java
import processing.video.*;

Capture video;
PImage image1, image2; //Images à comparer
int videoVar = 1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  video = new Capture(this, Capture.list()[61]);
  video.start();
}

void draw() {
    image1 = video.get();
    int m = videoVar;
    while (m == videoVar) {
      //println(m);
    }
    image2 = video.get();
    //image(image1, 0, 0);
    //image(image2, width/2, 0);
}

void captureEvent(Capture video) {
  video.read();
  videoVar = videoVar*(-1);
}
```

The problem is that the while loop, which is supposed to act as a custom delay basically, never exits it self. It only does so if there's something inside the while loop, as a "print('m');" for example. The thing is, printing takes time, and I want my program to be as fast as possible.

Would anyone have a suggestion on what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the `while` loop to continuously loop itself, regardless of what's inside it.

You shouldn't use a loop as a delay at all. You could possibly use the `delay()` function.

But better yet, you should use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to check whether a certain amount of time has gone by. Or you should just set a `boolean` value that you set from the `captureEvent()` function.

If you still can't figure it out, please be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do here.

**Edit:** Just for fun, can you try adding the keyword `volatile` in front of the declaration of `videoVar`? The line would look like this: `volatile int videoVar = 1;` Then try the `while` loop without anything in it.

But besides that, I'm recommending that you change your code to look like this:

```
boolean doThing = false;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
}

void draw() {
  if(doThing){
    // do the thing
    doThing = false;
  }
}

void captureEvent(Capture video) {
  doThing = true;
}
```

That's just an example, but hopefully it demonstrates the approach. Alternatively, you could use the `noLoop()` and `loop()` functions:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
}

void draw() {
  // do the thing
  noLoop();
}

void captureEvent(Capture video) {
  loop();
}
```

Comment: That's what I was expecting as well! The delay and millis() functions aren't that useful because I want to avoid any fixed amount of time. I thought about using a boolean, but setting it alternatively to True/False is longer than just multiplying a integer by (-1). The thing I'm trying to do is just storing in two variables two frames that are consecutive, as fast as it can go. Hence, using a fixed amount of time isn't fast, as there could be less than the defined amount of time (33ms for 30frames/s) between the time when the first image is stored and the time when the second image is availabl